# In jQuery, how can I tell if the current object is hidden or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Before I call:

```
$('myObject').show();
```

I want to know if it is currently hidden or visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test this with the css() function:

```
if ($('myObject').css('display') == 'none') {
  $('myObject').show();
}
```

EDIT:

Wasn't aware of how cool the :hidden selector is. My suggestion is still useful for testing other attributes, but Alex's suggestion is nicer in this case.

Comment: I think the value for display is 'none', or for visibility is 'hidden'.

Comment: The :hidden and :visible selectors check both display and visibility as well as hidden inputs.

Answer (score 40):

There's 2 ways to do it, that I know of:

```
if ($('#something').is(':hidden')) { }
```

or

```
if ($('#something').is(':visible')) { }
```

They should both work.

You can also do something like this:

```
$('#something:hidden').show();
$('#something:visible').hide();
```

Which will only call .show() if the item is already hidden, or only call .hide() if the item is already visible.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use the Toggle `$(this).toggle();`

Comment: +1, This is a much simple solution if you only want to toggle state of the object.

Answer (score 3):

From [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_determine_the_state_of_a_toggled_element.3F):

```
 var isVisible = $('myObject').is(':visible');
 var isHidden = $('myObject').is(':hidden');
```